# When not to use existential 'there'?

Tags: grammar, existentials

Some dictionaries and grammar books in my language give funny restrictions for "There is ~" structure.

A newer grammar book changed a little and now says it's ok to use "There is(are) ~" for proper nouns as long as it's a new theme. Before they said that only when put up several names in a row it's ok to use the structure for proper nouns or nouns led by 'the'.

Those books and dictionaries say "There is" is to bring up a new theme and so use of 'the' is limited to where grammatically needed case such as with a superlative adjective or followed by a modifier like a relative pronoun or an of-clause.

But I've learned here (and there) that it's not actually right.

I wonder why those books and dictionaries in my language are like that.

I wonder if it's ok to say "Is there Mr. Smith here today?"

[edit to add]
An example I found on Google is clearly not a new theme:

> e.g. There's the girl I was talking about.（The New Cambridge English Course 3 Teacher's Book, 1992）

[edit to add]
It's been a while, but now I think I can summarize it. When a thing or two you know come to your mind as relevant items to an idea, you can say "There's the ... and the ...", but when you ask a question, "Is there ...?" is an expression to ask if something ever exist or not, so it's not grammatical and sounds strange if it's used to ask if one of the staff is present today. (Nov. 27, 2016)

Comment: Sorry, but I really haven't a clue what you're actually asking. It's not OK to say "Is there Mr. Smith here today?" it would be "Is Mr. Smith here today?"

Comment: Please think twice before click on the 'close'.

Comment: Your question does make me and some other people uneasy. I haven't VTC'd, but for the rules that your book provides, it's really better if you provide examples. That way, we won't have to do some rocket science to figure out what a grammar book has said that is presumably incorrect.

Comment: Then you can ask so and closing it doesn't solve it.

Comment: Posters here are students to English and come here to ask their questions and not to give you quiz. They can't be perfect question givers.

Comment: I tried my best to translate what they say on their books. I do have some example sentences and will add them on the post. I am trying to read the answer below which seems very good one.

Comment: Note that names could be used in an existential. Consider: *A: "Who was at the party last night?" B: "There was Mary, Sue, Fred, Matt, and Sam."* -- 2002 *CGEL*, page 1400. Also, on page 1393, there is the example: *"There's Sue to consider."*

Comment: The edit page doesn't allow me to click the 'save' button. I try here. 
The older grammar book I have says this is not correct: "There is Mt. Fuji in Shizuoka Prefecture." and this should be "Mt. Fuji is in Shizuoka Prefecture." But this is by StoneyB: "Are there any mountains whose peaks straddle national borders?" "Well, there's Mt. Everest on the border between China and Nepal."
The same author says in his newer grammar book it's ok to use a proper noun with this structure as long as it's a new theme, but no example sentence is given that it's hard to think what he means by 'a new theme'.

Comment: And a couple of example sentences showing the way to use this structure with several individual's names or things led by 'the'. These are from a dictionary written by completely different people. (These are dated a little older but still in use publicly and free of use on the net): 1. “Is there anyone coming to dinner?” “Yes, there's Harry and there's also Mrs. Jones.” 2. I need money. There's the gas, the water and the electricity to pay.

Comment: The example #1 is using separate 'there's' followed by a single name but this is given as an example of usage with multiple proper names.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Context** is, once again, the important factor!

It's important to distinguish between the existential *there*, and the simple adverbial use (Where is the ball? The ball is *there*.)

Let's have a look at your example sentence:

> There's the girl I was talking about.

Now, this sentence can mean two different things. Without context, we cannot tell which of the two is meant. It can be simple adverbial use:

> We are talking, possibly about a girl, when a girl enters the room.
>   “There is the girl I was talking about!”

In this case *there* is not an existential *where*, it simply indicates the position of the girl: she is *there*, walking through the door.

Now, the same sentence *could* be existential:

> I am giving you a list of important people in my life: my family, my best friend, oh, and
>   “There is the girl I was talking about.”

Now, I wasn't just now talking about that girl! I have been talking about that girl at some earlier occasion, but right now I was talking about a different subject. So *in context*, that girl **is** a new theme!

Now, let's have a look at your other sentence:

> *Is there Mr. Smith here today?

This sentence is not grammatical. The question is: what do you want to ask?
Let's suppose you are at a reception desk at a company, and you are looking for a specific Mr. Smith — you want to talk to him. 
You [i]know[/] that he exists, so there is now reason to inquire about his existence! You just want to know whether he is *present* or not:

> Is Mr. Smith here today?

You can even use *there*, for instance when you are not on the premises (let's assume you ask for him by phone):

> Is Mr. Smith there?

Keep in mind that in that last sentence, *there* is simply adverbial, **not** existential!

Now, you *could* use the existential *there*, if you actually are not sure whether Mr. Smith *exists*:

> Is there a Mr. Smith working here?

Notice that you are not asking about *the* Mr. Smith, you are asking if there is *any* person by the name of Mr. Smith. Obviously, you *are* introducing a new theme here. Even if you have been talking about the Mr. Smith you are looking for, you can use this:

> I was told to bring this package to Mr. Smith, but I don't know where he works. Is there a Mr. Smith working at this company?

It seems that the second *Mr. Smith* is not a “new theme”, but actually, it is. The first Mr. Smith is a specific Mr. Smith I should deliver a package to, the second Mr. Smith is a hypothetical Mr. Smith that may or may not exist. I am implying that they *may* be the same people, but I cannot assume that — I'm not even sure if that second Mr. Smith exists!

Comment: Nicely put. In the case of (hypothetical, possibly non-existent) Mr Smith we do indeed need the indefinite article. You could feasibly say *"Is there [a] roast chicken for dinner tonight"* with or without the article (concrete noun identifying the specific bird that was/will/might be cooked, or mass noun identifying the *substance* to be eaten). Come to that, you could replace ***there*** by ***it*** in my version with no significant change in meaning.

Comment: But say if you were on a small farm, where (at least *some* of) the chickens are known/named, so everyone knows which one is ***the** "fat chicken"*. In that context, I don't think you can really say *"Is there the fat chicken for tea?"*, but you *can* say *"Is **it** the fat chicken for tea?"*

Comment: @FumbleFingers indeed, it seems Mr. Smith is not a chicken. But notice the use of _the_: you cannot use the definite article in such constructions. In the existential examples I gave, I ask about **a** Mr. Smith, not **the** Mr. Smith. I _could_ ask if there is _fat chicken_ for tea, or even if there is _a fat chicken_ for tea, or if there is _a chicken named Petronella_ for tea, but not _the chicken_. In any case, I fear the poultry declines the invitation for tea.

Comment: Poultry, eh? First it's the turkeys refusing to vote for Christmas, then it's uppity chickens turning down invitations to tea. I suppose they think they're too good for the likes of us. (Personally, I blame Heston Blumenthal and [*The Fat Duck Restaurant*](http://www.thefatduck.co.uk/) for giving them all these fancy ideas! :)

Comment: You can also use it to express someone or something is acting in a specific manner, normally used when they are resuming a pattern of behavior.  As in "He got drunk and crashed his car?  There's the Robert Downey Jr that I knew in the 80's!"

Comment: @Kevin: isn't that a simple adverbial use of _there_?

Comment: @oerkelens, yes, it is. However, I thought someone learning English might not be familiar with that particular use of it.

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting it. I think those books and dictionaries are confusing because they don't say anything that there are 'existential' and not 'existential' use of 'there'.